# Contactless virtual Visa card payments in Yodobashi, Japan

Tags: japan, payment-cards, shopping, contactless

Can someone living in Japan please find out if contactless payments made through Google Pay or Apple Pay are accepted in Yodobashi? And specifically, if they are done through a virtual Visa card through one of these systems, if they are eligible for the special 5% tourist discount paying with Visa card (on top of the standard 8% tourist discount).

The reason is that I want to make a large purchase and my card issuer recently switched to MasterCard for physical cards. But I still have one virtual Visa card.

Thank you!

Comment: To partially answer my own question, I found out that Google Pay is accepted in Yodobashi as well as other places:

https://pay.google.com/intl/ja_jp/about/where-to-use/ .

Hopefully, someone can help me find out if a virtual Visa card is eligible for the 5% additional discount.

Comment: Apparently my answer was rather incomplete, despite being the payment information provided by Yodobashi themselves, so I deleted it. Anyway, as a side note: to use Google Pay in Japan, the device has to support "osaifu keitai" (NFC-F / NFC Felica), which unless the device is made for the Japanese market it probably won't. I believe all recent iPhone models support this, regardless of where they are made for. See [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/japanlife/comments/7ll5vk/osaifu_keitai_on_nonj_smartphones/) for more info on that.

Comment: @john The thing with your answer was that it did not say if paying with a virtual Visa card would be included in the discount promotion or not - just that one can pay with Google Pay. Thank you anyway for your answer even if it didn't have all the information, but also especially for this additional NFC info. I hope the iPhone I have works for my purposes since my other phone definitely won't. I think I'll just have to find out the complete answer myself when I visit :p

Comment: Have a nice trip! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of November 2019, almost no businesses in Japan accepted contactless payments by international cards or virtual cards, due to inadequate equipment or the cashier not knowing how to (or not caring enough to) set the machine to accept contactless payments from virtual international cards.

The only business that I can recall accepted virtual contactless payments was the Mamma Aiuto shop inside the Ghibli Museum.

Hopefully things will be easier during/after the Olympics!

Comment: However, through a loophole I was able to get a physical Visa card from my bank and buy the item that I wanted with discount :D

Comment: _"Hopefully things will be easier during/after the Olympics!"_ - I wouldn't be too hopeful!

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯...... one can dream